# how to add new column in ms access table with this criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

i have two msaccess tables

tableA

```
textA numA
bd    1
as    0
aa    2
cc    4
```

tableB

```
textB 
ss
aa
bd
as
```

how to write an sql query to add one column called numB in table B so that final table B would be

tableB  ( basically fetching values from tableA )

```
textB  numB
ss     0      ( because ss is not there in table A )
aa     2
bd     1
as     0
```

Comment: Unless your application requires duplicate copies of your numA values ... don't do it.  Just look up the numA values when you need them.  Life will be easier if the numA value for "aa" ever changes from 2 to 7 --- only need change it in one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This SQL will make a new table called tblFooC

```
SELECT tblFooB.TextB, nz([NumA],0) AS Expr1 INTO tblFooC
FROM tblFooB LEFT JOIN tblFooA ON tblFooB.TextB = tblFooA.TextA;
```

You could then delete table tblFooB and rename tblFooC to tblFooB

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in one query. You can create TableC from tables A & B and then rename and/or delete so that table C becomes table B, or you can run a DDL query to add a column to Table B. I suggest the second option.

To add a column:

```
ALTER TABLE TableB ADD COLUMN NumB Integer
```

To update:

```
UPDATE TableA 
RIGHT JOIN TableB ON TableA.TextA = Tableb.TextB 
SET TableB.BumB = Nz([NumA],0);
```